# Casting String to NSURL returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, image, nsurl

I'm trying to get an image from url like this:

```
var string = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyAJeHxZaZuNsYimNCJ4r0yuO-OYM8cINOI&center=6.241381,-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|6.241381,-75.595083&signature=u7sM3m2h-qFSJoARR7cqD0CSBvU="

let url = NSURL(string: string.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!)

if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
      let image = UIImage(data: data)
}
```

but it returns nil the **`url`**. It seems like the url doesn't exists but it is, if you go to the url you will see an image.

So what is the problem with the cast?  or how can I get this image.

Comment: Are you entering that URL on a real iOS device browser or using your computer's browser?

Comment: @LeoDabus I tried without removing the percent and the same thing.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm using my computer's browser.

Comment: You must use a URL that works from an actual iOS device. Test the URL using Mobile Safari and see what you get.

Comment: It works on iOS device @rmaddy

Comment: What's actually `nil`? `url`, `data`, or `image`?

Comment: the url @rmaddy

Comment: Good question, I checked and tried various SO questions, they didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the vertical bars (`|`) in the query part of your URL. They should be escaped as `%7C`.

Here's how I would construct the URL which auto-escape the query part:

```
var components = NSURLComponents(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap")!
components.query = "key=AIzaSyAJeHxZaZuNsYimNCJ4r0yuO-OYM8cINOI&center=6.241381,-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|6.241381,-75.595083&signature=u7sM3m2h-qFSJoARR7cqD0CSBvU="

if let url = components.url {
    // ...
}
```

If you are using Swift 3, `NSURLComponents` is renamed to `URLComponents`

Comment: There is one way to make it generally for differents urls, look that the url is from some coordinates given by GoogleMaps, so what about if the url comes with another parameters... The `components.query` will works also ?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I am loading images in my application using [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage)

```
let url = NSURL(string:"someUrl")
                self.imgView.af_setImageWithURL(url!, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil,  imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: false, completion:  { (error) in
                // do Something when asynchronous image loading is completed
            })
```

**EDIT**
Your url contains | which is not valid for url so you can use PercentEncoding.

Here is an example

```
let strurl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyAJeHxZaZuNsYimNCJ4r0yuO-OYM8cINOI&center=6.241381,-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|6.241381,-75.595083&signature=u7sM3m2h-qFSJoARR7cqD0CSBvU="
let myURL = NSURL(string: strurl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!)
self.imgView.af_setImageWithURL(myURL!, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil,  imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5), runImageTransitionIfCached: false, completion:  { (error) in
            // do Something when asynchronous image loading is completed
        })
```

Comment: Try yourself with the given URL.

Comment: The problem is that my NSURL is returning nil, so you can't download the image

Comment: I'm getting this message with the new `NSURL` : 
 [link url](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AIzaSyAJeHxZaZuNsYimNCJ4r0yuO-OYM8cINOI&center=6.241381,-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color:0x0000ff%7Cweight:5%7C6.241381,-75.595083&signature=u7sM3m2h-qFSJoARR7cqD0CSBvU=)

Comment: you are getting this because pipe "|" is converted to "%7C".

Comment: @Mr.UB so what can I do to see the image ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add percent encoding to your query as follow:

**Swift 2.3**

```
let domainAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?"
let query = "key=AIzaSyAJeHxZaZuNsYimNCJ4r0yuO-OYM8cINOI&center=6.241381,-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|6.241381,-75.595083&signature=u7sM3m2h-qFSJoARR7cqD0CSBvU="
if let queryPercentEncoded = query.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet()),
    let url = NSURL(string: domainAPI + queryPercentEncoded) {
    print(url)
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
if let queryPercentEncoded = query.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: domainAPI + queryPercentEncoded) {
    print(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(I haven't used a key based authentication, so some parts may need to be modified.)*

First, you need a properly percent-escaped URL string without signature:

```
let key = "AI...OI" // better hide your actual key in a public space...
let rawURLString = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=\(key)&center=6.241381%2B-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color%3A0x0000ff%7Cweight%3A5%7C6.241381%2B-75.595083"
//`rawURLString` needs to be a valid string representation of URL.
assert(NSURL(string: rawURLString) != nil)
```

And then, generate a base64-encoded signature for the URL string:

```
let encodedSignature: String = generateEncodedSignature(rawURLString, secret: yourSecretKey)
```

After that, you can create a signed URL string:

```
let signedURLString = "\(rawURLString)&signature=\(encodedSignature)"
```

(I believe you have some functionality to generate a signature or signed url in your app, modify above code according to it.)

The content of `signedURLString` should look like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?key=AI...OI&center=6.241381%2B-75.595083&zoom=13&size=600x300&path=color%3A0x0000ff%7Cweight%3A5%7C6.241381%2B-75.595083&&signature=u7...=
```

(`signature` may not start with "u7".)

And create `NSURL` using the `signedURLString`. Do not remove percent encodings.

```
let url = NSURL(string: signedURLString)
```